# Upload file & download a file in response using volley

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

I would like to upload one file on server through android device. Once the file is uploaded on server it modifies it & sent back to client.

Can you please help how to achieve it through volley in request I have to upload the file & in response am getting a file after applying some modification on uploaded file.  After getting the file in response need to save it in mobile device.

Got one example from [Github](https://github.com/huluhive/android-volley-file-upload) in which a file was uploaded on server through SimpleMultiPartRequest class but in response was getting string response. In my case am getting status as success or failure along with the modified file.

Comment: Check this example https://mobikul.com/downloading-files-using-volley/

Comment: @AnasMehar thanks for reply. Code is for downloading a file from server can you please let me know how to send a file in  same request object. Can I simply call method add file method with key name & file path on InputStreamVolleyObject class object to upload a file on server

Comment: Above you say you already upload file to server so put those method in InputStreamVolleyObject  and access using object

Comment: @AnasMehar In github sample  they are making use of  SimpleMultiPartRequest  class whose parent is  MultiPartRequest . In link you shared they are making own custom request class InputStreamVolleyRequest whose parent is Request class. I don't think we have access to addFile method in out custom class as its extended to different parent class